# corona sdk scrollableView

Tags: ios, titanium, coronasdk

Hi I am new to `Corona SDK` and I used to use `Titanium SDK

There is `scrollableView` in `Titanium SDK`, but I want to use something like this using `Corona SDK`

Below is the link about `scrollableView` from `Titanium SDK`

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/ScrollableView

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the widget library supports a scrollView.  See:

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/newScrollView.html